# Xcode #Include file problems after update from 3.2.6 to 4.5.1

Tags: c++, xcode, include, xcode4.5

I've had the oddest #include file problem since upgrading a C++ project from Xcode 3.2.6 to Xcode 4.5.1:  An #include header file for one of my statically linked library cannot be located.  I have no other undefined symbol errors for the entire project.

The #include is located in a prefix header, "MacClient_Prefix.pch" (I am NOT precompiling headers):

```
#include "Framework/Base/BaseEnvironment.h"
```

This header file (BaseEnvironment.h) is located in a a completely different folder hierarchy related to the statically linked library.

The errors:

```
/Users/StephenDev/Documents/dev/WordMenu/Projects/MacClient/Xcode/WordMenuBaseEnv.h
/Users/StephenDev/Documents/dev/WordMenu/Projects/MacClient/Xcode/WordMenuBaseEnv.h:26:10: 'Framework/Base/BaseEnvironment.h' file not found
/Users/StephenDev/Documents/dev/WordMenu/Projects/MacClient/Xcode/<built-in>:148:2: In file included from <built-in>:148:
/Users/StephenDev/Documents/dev/WordMenu/Projects/MacClient/Xcode/<command line>:4:10: In file included from <command line>:4:
/Users/StephenDev/Documents/dev/WordMenu/Projects/MacClient/Xcode/MacClient_Prefix.pch:9:10: In file included from
     /Users/StephenDev/Documents/dev/WordMenu/Projects/MacClient/Xcode/MacClient_Prefix.pch:9:
```

I'm fairly sure the User Header File paths are correctly set for the project.

What's odd is that if I COMMENT OUT the #include, then I get hundreds of actual errors for missing symbols from the rest of the code.  So clearly, the file IS being found when the prefix header is used for compiling the project files.

I've even tried to EXPLICITLY specify the FULL path to the header file in the #include, but that wrecks the including for the rest of the project build.

My include paths in the build options are project-relative, and I think that may be connected to this issue.  Could the issue have something to do with the include path for derived data or intermediates?

The build project for the statically linked library, which is included in the "main" project that has the error, DOES define the header files to be "public".  However, a clean build / rebuild of the main project does not (presently) appear to re-build the statically linked library.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

> What's odd is that if I COMMENT OUT the #include, then I get hundreds of actual errors for missing symbols from the rest of the code. So clearly, the file IS being found when the prefix header is used for compiling the project files.

#include errors are fatal and so the compiler will not continue on to display all the errors resulting from the missing #include.

```
#include <foo>
There's no way this is legal C++...
```

results:

```
main.cpp:1:10: fatal error: 'foo' file not found
#include <foo>
         ^
1 error generated.
```

The fact that there's no other error does not mean that the second line was interpreted as valid C++ code.

Comment: you are correct, but I'm still unsure why I can't locate the file -- it seems as if it should be along the path I specified.

Comment: There should be a flag you can add to the compiler so it will tell you the paths it searches to help you debug this. I don't recall it at the moment though.

Comment: Thanks -- this WAS the problem.  The User include path was off by ONE "/.." and it was masking that fact that all those other errors were disappearing.  I didn't find the flag -- would be great to know it for the future.